# Finding next available Product ID

Tags: sql

Firstly I must apologise for the simplicity of the question, but I am new to SQL and am struggling with the query.

I have a database which lists our product numbers I would like to create a query to tell us what the next available number is.

The product number is recorded in the Prod_ID colum in the format of 000000.00000

The first 6 numbers are for the prduct type and the 2nd 5 numbers are for the product variants (different colour for example). The only part I am interested in is finding the next available number for the product ID (The first 6 numbers)

There is no danger of the ID being used after I have found it as I will be the only person managing this.

I have tried:

```
Select IsNull(max(Prod_ID), 0) + 1 as MaxSID FROM Products
```

but I get a 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'failed. Invali' to data type int'

Comment: Is there any chance you could split these two values apart? You are storing two pieces of information in a single column which is in violation 1NF.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? If this is sql server you could look at using a sequence. Honestly I would probably break this into 2 tables. Product and ProductVariants but that may be a bigger project than you can do at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @Prod_ID varchar(20)
set @prod_id = '000000.00000'

select cast(
        substring(@prod_id,8,5) -- Get second part of string
        as int) +1 as TheNext
```

- The substring extracts the second part of the ID
- The cast converts it to an integer
- +1 gives you the next value

So you actual code would read

```
SELECT cast(substring(prod_id,8,5) as int) +1 as TheNext FROM table WHERE prod_id=123
```

*NOTE: even though the above will work, I agree with the comments about redesigning this if allowed*